# Проблема с корзиной на Jommla

Tags: joomla

при нажатии на кнопку товара добавить в корзину товар добавляется, но это видно только, если перезагрузить страницу. как исправить, чтобы когда добавляешь товар в корзину, он сразу отображался в корзине без перезагрузки?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете 'Virtuemart', вам необходимо активировать модуль `VirtueMart Shopping Cart` который по стандарту устанавливается с ядром `Virtuemart`. Данный модуль обновляется посредством `AJAX` и в корзине добавляется продукт без перезагрузки.
PS как настроить читаем [тут](http://ktonanovenkogo.ru/joomla/virtuemart-joomla/nastrojki-internet-magazina-virtuemart-sdelat-srazu-posle-ustanovki-2.html#b336x280)

Comment: да virtuemart использую

Comment: и? у вас активирован данный модуль?

Comment: а ты случайно не знаешь, как активировать модуль, если в Joomla установлен K2?

Comment: Virtuemart и K2 не связанны между собой, если магазин работает на Virtuemart. для активации модуля необходимо зайти в "Менеджер модулей", в правом верхнем углу нажать кнопку "Новый" и в списке доступных модулей выбрать "VirtueMart Shopping Cart", после включить модуль и активировать в нужной позиции шаблона.

Comment: А почему тогда не работает? Я подключил и активировал.

Comment: а вы уверенны что в настройках Virtuemart установлено работа корзины методом Ajax?  почитайте тут 
http://ktonanovenkogo.ru/joomla/virtuemart-joomla/nastrojki-internet-magazina-virtuemart-sdelat-srazu-posle-ustanovki-2.html#b336x280

Comment: но это ведь старая статья, она устарела. сейчас ведь так не получится, я не могу найти, что нужно

Comment: статья старая - а логика включения Ajax таже... какая версия Virtuemart у вас ?     3.0 ?

Comment: 3.0.16. Логика та же, но вот как же найти. Должно ведь было измениться

Comment: и что можно сделать?

Comment: всё работало корректно раньше, но один "умелец" делал правки и что-то напортачил, в итоге появился баг. как думаешь, если сначала всё работало нормально, а потом такой баг, то это из за чего? потому-что я вроде все проверил и я в одном месте увидел в настройках ajax и поставил галочку и все равно не работает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54126/discussion-between-arsen-and-dem).